# Google Maps are not showing up in a signed apk

Tags: android, google-maps, release

I know this is a common question and usually the solution is to generate a separate key for release. I've done it several times and my API key in developers console contains two different SHA1-fingerprints: one for debug from AndroidStudio and on for release from my own keystore. I have signed the app with the same keystore and enabled Google Maps Android API v2 in the console. But still the maps activity shows just the white screen with 'Google' in the left bottom corner.

Are there any suggestions how to solve the problem?

Comment: so you got the google maps api key?? where did you put it?? if you are having difficulties then create a new maps activity, it will then show you the xml file where you need to put the key in, and then delete that activity.

Comment: @Tacos I put it in the in the automatically generated string-value in google_maps_api.xml that is put in the manifest file afterwards

Comment: Ok, cool. do you see any errors in the log cat, regarding maps api key? if no errors, when you move your finger on the map, does the map magically appear. That happened to me before, cause my fragment layout was screwed.

Comment: It is happening due to you added *debug SHA1* key on google, So please create SHA1 for *release* mode, fore more info **Kindly have a look on this video How to create SHA1 for release** https://youtu.be/g75cZXjmuj8

Answer (score 77, accepted):

It sounds like you only have the API key entered in the debug google_maps_api.xml.  Also, it sounds like you're using the same API key for debug and release, but you still need to enter it in the google_maps_api.xml under the release folder as well as the one in the debug folder.

It's a little confusing, because when the project is in Android view, you can only see the debug file (although it should have `(debug)` in parenthesis next to it in that view).

In order to modify the release version, switch to Project view by using the dropdown in the upper left of the Project Explorer.  Then, expand `app/src/`, and you will see subfolders `debug` and `release`.  Under there, you should see two separate google_maps_api.xml files under `debug/res/values` and `release/res/values`.

Make sure that the API key is populated in the google_maps_api.xml file under the `release/res/values` folder, since this is the one that will be used for the signed release apk.

[image]

Comment: Thank you a lot! That was the problem! I used Android view and didn't suspect there are two different folders for it. I wonder why isn't it mentioned anywhere. Anyway, thank you!

Comment: @Daniel Nugent I have added api key in both values folders (debug &release) still map fragment is not showing.

Comment: @payaltuteja do your logs show any errors related to the map?

Comment: @payal you will need to look at the logs while running the release version.

Comment: Its giving authorization failure

Comment: @payaltuteja could plz comment wat was the issue? I've followed the above steps but still map is not being shown!

Comment: @Saleem Khan C H It was giving authorization failure. I have checked the logs.In releae apk logs sha1 was different as given at a time of debug mode on console and i have added that logs sha1 on google developer console and issue get resolved

Comment: Thanks @payaltuteja

Comment: yeah :) I made the configuration in gradle file to build the release apk automatically and the problem was solved!

Comment: @DanielNugent thank you you save my second day. from yesterday i facing same problem and create many keys .

Answer (score 25):

If you chose **Google Play App Signing** then your App's `SHA-1` will be different one when it will be released.

Because Google remove your uploaded certificate and then sign the App with a new one,

So you have to know the new `SHA-1` key.

*(You don't have to follow the log for release and track the new `SHA-1` generated)*

[image]

---

You can compare the 2 `SHA-1` keys.

[Origin answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44585684/5559741)

Comment: I put the App Signing Certificate SHA1 as you shown above, but still the map is not visiable.

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for after more than hour. Thanks!!

Comment: Thanks a lot. mean while we have to set two SHA1 in google clound console.

Comment: Welcome @Vrajesh

Comment: where to put this key?

Comment: Thanks i worked for me after spending hours on it :)

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by looking at https://play.google.com/console in the left menu configuration then integrity of the app and copy the SHA1 of the upload key certificate that is below the SHA1 Certificate of the app signing key and add it in the same api key of https://console.cloud.google.com/. This way I didn't have to make changes to the apk.

If it doesn't work for you add both and try.

Answer (score 0):

you are using a version of sha1. you need to again generate SHA1 using command prompt after making you apk signed.

Steps to regenerate SHA1 is go to cmd and give the command like below:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_91\bin>keytool -list -v -keystore
```

"C:\Your key store path\keystores\android.jks"

1)go to your java in program file open java version like jre1.8.0

2)open bin folder and run command like above follwed by your key store path that you have generated when you generated the signed apk 
after running this command on cmd you need to provide password of signed app and your SHA1 will be gerarated.

3)copy the sha1 and paste into console.developer with your package name within your api key.

Answer (score 0):

I did a lot of things to fix these but any solution not fix my problem 
to fix these issue I did these things

1. Create signed apk with new keystore file make sure that the you will create that in release mode
2. After creating the signed apk you should note the keystore path where you save your keystore file.
3. You also need to use your google map API key with your release mode and debug mode both, you can use same API key with both but make sure that you should add two different sha keys for your single api key on google console.
4. You should  go to use the path of bin folder of java from c drive because keystore tool is inside bin folder so 
   suppose your file is like C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_11\bin
   so you should follow this path to your android studio terminal 
   change the path to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_11\bin
   and then type this command:

   ```
   keytool -list -v -keystore "/Users/NT/Desktop/generalkey.jks"(adress of your keystore file)
   ```
5. Now by doing these you will get the sha key copy that key
6. Go to google console/credentials
7. Now go to your api you will see edit option go to edit and past your sha key into it and save it .
8. Run your code.

Answer (score 0):

It's too late to answer but may be helpful for others if they phase the same issue.

If adding key in the release did not work then please check your SHA key in your jks file and add the same key in google play [google api console](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials)

To get released SHA open your terminal and type

```
Asad-MacBook-Air:~ asad$ keytool -list -v -keystore /your/path/keystore.jks
```

and then check SHA, it should be the same as it is used in google api console.

Answer (score 0):

this happend to me because we need two google maps api keys one for the debug and another one for the release, you can check in :

```
C:\Users\username\AndroidStudioProjects\yourapp\app\src\ debug \res\values
```

and you’ll find an xml with your api key like:

AIza...etc

but if you check here:

```
C:\Users\username\AndroidStudioProjects\yourapp\app\src\ release \res\values
```

you will find an xml but without api key inside like:

```
<string name="google_maps_key" templateMergeStrategy="preserve" 
     translatable="false">YOUR_KEY_HERE</string>
```