# Google Maps not loading after publishing on play store even after updating SHA 1 fingerprint for release key

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play, google-maps-android-api-2, google-maps-api-2

A newbie here to google maps api and android app development.
I am facing some strange issue and struggling with this from two days. I have developed an app in which I have used Google maps. I have launched the app to play store. The google map loads perfectly fine when I install the signed apk directly to mobile but not when I install through play store.

I have updated google maps api console with release key SHA 1 fingerprint. I am not able to find any solutions online also and did not get any support from google support team also. Somebody please help!

Comment: Probably you're using the fingerpint for debuggin. Please check this [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/signup#release-cert)

Comment: Adding the SHA-1 fingerprint from App Signing certificate in play console to the credentials in google developers console should work.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

If u have enabled the App Signing Feature in the Developer Console, then it's clearly written in the documentation that the Upload Certificate is only needed by Google for authentication and that upload certificate is removed before installing the application on the user's phone. So, u also need to give the App Signing Certificate SHA under the key which you have enabled for Google Maps API.
The App Signing Page is as I have attached the screenshot for your convenience...
In the image I have marked which you need to give as **additional** credentials

[image]

Comment: Thank you Chandan Suri. I also figured out the same and it worked.

Comment: Your Welcome... Happy to help.

Comment: this valid answer!!

Comment: Issue remains :(

Comment: where to use this sh1 key ?

Comment: this key has to be used in a file present in the maps activity related file, there you need to paste your SSH key, then it would run in the release mode as well...

Comment: @ChandanSuri bro can u help me out where to put SHA-1 certificate fingerprint..??

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the accepted answer: In the good old days you would create 2 API keys, one for debug and one for release. Each one used the relevant keystore SHA1 you have created. But due to "Google Play App Signing" the SHA1 you have used for your release version is not valid anymore (Google removes the release certificate including your SHA1 before uploading). So the easy solution is to get back in Play Store Console, copy SHA1 from App Signing Certificate (NOT from the Upload Certificate in the bottom!) and put it in the release Google Maps Android API, save and it will refresh without creating a new key.

Comment: i can't find where to put the copied sha1 from app signing certificate

Answer (score 1):

When you upload and publish the app play console uses your key for upload purpose only. To sign and publish each releases it uses different key certificates that you can find under

**Setup -> App Integrity section**

Just copy SHA-1 key from there and update it with google map api key. After that your map will start working.[image: Play console snap to show app signing]

Answer (score 0):

You can paste the copied sha1 in " restrict usage to your android apps " in restrict and rename Api key

Comment: This looks like it should've been a comment on Brian K.'s answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have any restriction and you are getting this error; make sure your debug/main key and release key are the same or release key is valid.