# Google Map is not displayed after I submitted my app to the Play store

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-studio-3.0

After I submitted my app to play store I noticed that map is not shown, I also noticed this problem is some how common; I tried all possible solutions but none of them have worked for me, the blank map is always displayed after I install/update my app, in some cases I managed to display map in release-apk, I still face the same proplem after I download my app from play store, notice that when map is displayed in release version, it does not display in debug version; some of these solutions are

`<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" android:value="@string/google_maps_key"/>`

and

`<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
    android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />`

I placed both tags inside application tag and outside application tag in manifest file, still not working.

I used SHA1 key that was generated by android studio and the another one generated me using `file.keystore`, still not working, I tired different api keys for debug and release apk in `google_map_api.xml` still not working; I don't know what else I should try.

thanks in advance

Comment: You mean you can't access maps on debugging mode but yes in released/downloaded apk? your statement is slight confusing. "After I SUBMITTED MY APP TO PLAYSTORE I noticed that map is NOT SHOWN" and " I still face the same proplem AFTER I DOWNLOAD MY APP FROM PLAYSTORE, notice that when map is DISPLAYED IN  RELEASE VERSION, it does not display in debug version;"

Comment: @jace The release apk is the one in my computer who's working not in play store

Comment: have you tried to debug it and put a message on onMapReady to see if it is loading the map? cause it's really a bit weird if it only loads in released apk but not in debug apk. Are you both accessing the debug and release apk with internet connection? (just guessing it might be because it happened to us while trying to build gmaps)

Comment: In this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44570930/google-maps-not-loading-after-publishing-on-play-store-even-after-updating-sha-1/44585684#44585684) I have found the answer to my problem

Answer (score 0):

When you want to upload the app to google play, you must change the HASH KEY and upload.

Comment: First do I have to generate anthor Sha 1 key, second where do I put that key?