# Google map api not showing in app when published to playstore

Tags: android, api, google-maps, key, sha1

Map does not show in an app I've published.

Here is what I've done:

1. created API key and added **Package name** and **SHA-1 certificate fingerprint** via restricting usage to Android apps in the credentials tab of the Google API manager

I am confused as to which **SHA-1 certificate fingerprint** I need to use so I created a key for each. I found 4 **SHA-1 certificate fingerprints** from:

1. `keytool -list -v -keystore mystore.keystore` command
2. from the comments in the **google_maps_api.xml** file
3. from the Google Play console App signing certificate
4. from the Google Play console Upload certificate

I am unfamiliar with App Signing and if there is anything more I need to do please let me know.
I very much want the map to appear on the app!
If someone could show me the steps to make this happen pleas help me!!!!! :(

- https://i.stack.imgur.com/1YgRJ.png "API Keys"
- https://i.stack.imgur.com/nSxXD.png "Terminal Command"
- https://i.stack.imgur.com/GBKFL.png "google_maps_api.xml comments"
- https://i.stack.imgur.com/IMgX3.png "App Signing"

Comment: Replace the SHA1 certificate with App signing SHA1 certificate hash key

Comment: I face the same issue ,
Here is a solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/44585684/3392323

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two google_maps_api.xml files in the app one for debug and another for release.

release : `app\src\release\res\values\google_maps_api.xml`

debug : `app\src\debug\res\values\google_maps_api.xml`

In your case the api key might be blank in `release google_maps_api.xml`

and if you didn't copy `SHA1` App signing in Play store. replace with existing `SHA1`