# Why google map does not display after publishing android map apps on google play store?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play

I published an app in google play store. Before publishing the app I test the app on my real device.But it does not show any problem.But after download the app from play store it shows problem. Google map does not load.

Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Did you use Google Places Api ? If yes, you should have enable billing account to use it. You can check here :https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/usage-and-billing

Comment: Have you added google map api key for release mode? It will be available at /src/release/res/values/google_maps_api.xml

Comment: Yes I added api key for release mode

Comment: check this also https://stackoverflow.com/a/44585684/5370550

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should check your project keys on Google developers console. I hope you are aware that `DEBUG` and `RELEASE` keys for a project are different. 
In addition to above, if you have enabled Google app Signing on play console, then the `RELEASE` key should match. 
Also check for the Google map API whether they are enabled for your project or not on the console.